# dependsOnMethods from testng with "or" statement

Tags: testng

I have a simple question.

Can you use a "or" statement inside a dependsOnMethods from testng

For example I have my test1 & test2 running and I would like my test3 to run if test1 or test2 did work

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for the moment: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1092